# Create a long list of random values, no duplicates

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, random, int

I want to create a list given two inputs, and under the condition that there cannot be any duplicates. The list should contain a random sequence of numbers. Then numbers in the list are positive integers.

- Input 1: the length of the list (var `samples`)
- Input 2: the highest number of the list (var `end`)

I know how to do this, but I want the list to contain a vast number of numbers, 1 million numbers, or more.
I have created 2 methods to solve this problem myself, both have their issues, on of them is `slow` the other produces a `MemoryError`.

Method 1, `MemoryError`:

```
import random

def create_lst_rand_int(end, samples):
    if samples > end:
        print('You cannot create this list')
    else:
        lst = []
        lst_possible_values = range(0, end)
        for item in range(0, samples):
            random_choice = random.choice(lst_possible_values)
            lst_possible_values.remove(random_choice)
            lst.append(random_choice)
        return lst

print create_lst_rand_int(1000000000000, 100000000001)
```

Method 2, `slow`:

```
import random

def lst_rand_int(end, samples):
    lst = []
    # lst cannot exist under these conditions
    if samples > end:
        print('List must be longer or equal to the highest value')
    else:
        while len(lst) < samples:
            random_int = random.randint(0, end)
            if not random_int in lst:
                lst.append(random_int)
        return lst

print lst_rand_int(1000000000000, 100000000001)
```

Since neither of my methods work well (method 1 does work better than method 2) I would like to know how I can create a list that meets my requirements better.

Comment: Does the list need to be in memory?

Comment: I just need a list stored somewhere where I can easily access it later. I would highly prefer it not to be in an external file.

Comment: Looking at all those zeros: if I did not mess up my calculation, the list amounts to a minimum of 3725 Gigabyte. Have you got all this memory?

Comment: I have 4gb of memory, 200gb of HDD.

Comment: And both 4 GB and 200 GB are way largar than the required 3725 GB.

Comment: On my system, a Python integer is 24 bytes (as reported by `sys.getsizeof`). The post asks for 100000000001 integers, which requires 2400000000024 bytes. That's 2235.17 GB (using Google for the convenient converstion), or roughly 2 TB. This will never come close to working on the listed machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the solution given in the docs:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample

> To choose a sample from a range of integers, use an xrange() object as an argument. This is especially fast and space efficient for sampling from a large population: sample(xrange(10000000), 60).

Or, in your case, `random.sample(xrange(0,1000000000000), 100000000001)`

This is still a giant data structure that may or may not fit in your memory. On my system:

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(1)
24
```

So 100000000001 samples will require 2400000000024 bytes, or roughly two terabytes. I suggest you find a way to work with smaller numbers of samples.

Comment: +1 But you didn't tell the reason `xrange` is faster than `range`: because `range` allocates the entire list in memory upfront, whereas `xrange` returns a generator thereby utilizing lazy allocation

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
temp = xrange(end+1)
random.sample(temp, samples)
```

[`random.sample()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) does not pick any duplicates.

Comment: When I run this script Instead exiting and throwing a Memory Error it freezes my system.

Answer (score 1):

Since `sample` always returns a list, you're out of luck with such a large size. Try using a generator instead:

```
def rrange(min, max):
    seen = set()
    while len(seen) <= max - min:
        n = random.randint(min, max)
        if n not in seen:
            seen.add(n)
            yield n
```

This still requires memory to store seen elements, but at least not everything at once.

Comment: I was thinking about this approach - it sure beats the OP's second one - but it will still end up building an equally large data structure. Just a set rather than a list.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: the key is that the structure is built gradually, so you can take measures when you go out of mem, like swap parts of it out etc.

Comment: I have a problem when I run it I get this instead of the lst. <generator object rrange at 0x7fe8af785690>. Also the function should take the inputs, number of numbers in the list, the highest number in the list

Comment: @JebediahKerman: this is a generator object. You're supposed to use a `for` loop with it: `for n in rrange(...)`.

Comment: would be nice to have a complete answer, I am fairly new to python

Answer (score 0):

You could use a set instead of a list, and avoid checking for duplicates.

```
def lr2(end, samples):
    lst = set()
    # lst cannot exist under these conditions
    if samples > end:
        print('List must be longer or equal to the highest value')
    else:
        for _ in range(samples):
            random_int = random.randint(0, end)
            lst.add(random_int)
        return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your sample size is such a large percentage of the items being sampled, a much faster approach is to shuffle the list of items and then just remove the first or last n items.

```
import random

def lst_rand_int(end, samples):
    lst = range(0, end)
    random.shuffle(lst)
    return lst[0:samples]
```

If `samples > end` it will just return the whole list

If the list is too large for memory, you can break it into parts and store the parts on disc.  In that case a random choice should be made to choose a section, then an item in the section and remove it for each sample required.